# Motor part winding start

Tags: motors, cooling, compressors

I have a BITZER compressor type 4GE-23Y-40P, with a part winding start option

[image]

Nennspannung = nominal voltage = 380-420

Frequ = frequency = 50

Betr. strom = maximal operating current = 43.9

Anlaufstrom = starting current (A(Y) with the first winding, A(YY) second winding) = [A(Y)=97, A(YY)=158]

I am confused about what current should I consider in the sizing of the compressor starter parts (contactor, fuse, circuit breaker, thermal overload relay)?

Thanks in advance